# Android window with notifications like facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'am developing an android app, and I would like to have a window to show user notifications most like the facebook window, not necessary equals...
I just don't know what is the best way to make a window like that.
Is using an activity declared in manifest file like:

```
<activity
   android:name="OverlayActivity"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

?

I want something like this:

[image]

If anyone could show me an example I would appreciate that.
Thank you all, and please help me with this.

Comment: You mean fb messenger app and its contact icons floating over the "desktop"?

Comment: No. Is not that. Is the window in facebook app where you can see your notifications, likes, comments etc...